# Retrieve data from ajax typed in the search box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have cloned the search box but the typed suggestions are not displaying. So, I'd tried to get the data manually via ajax. I'd  inspect and checked in network log and the XHR file is available. I'm not sure how to connect/link the searched word typed in the input box with the XHR file to fetch the data.

I have tried $.get and $.ajax method to get data from the network. But not sure how to get suggestion of the word (example: puma) typed in the input search box. 'Request URL: https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=flatsome_ajax_search_products&query=puma'.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'https://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: {},
  });
```

console.log(data);
All the data's of the ajax call for the searched keyword needs to be consoled logged.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking here, sorry. What search box? Why did you clone it? What does that have to do with the question you're asking? What do you mean by "XHR file"? Why, in your ajax call, are you sending no data? Why do you think you can even send data in a `get` request?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Our product page has already has the search box. It will show suggestion of the product typed in it. We are trying to add the same search box to the home page. So i'd copy all the element of the search box in product page to the home page. The functionality is not working. So I'd decided to get the suggestion result from the ajax call in the network log. Appreciate your help.

Comment: From the URLs, it appears you're on a WordPress site. Who implemented the product page search box? Is it from a plugin, for example?